# Python: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, input

I'm getting an `invalid literal for int() with base 10` where it seems as if the input stream is concatenating values generated in a loop.

```
def collectData():
    lst = makeCases()
    cases = int(input())
    for i in range(cases):
        size = int(input())
        case = []
        for j in range(size):
            value = int(input())
            case +=[value]
        insert(lst,case)
    return lst
```

That is the function generating the issue. The value and size variables are the problem as they seem to concatenate subsequent values before the conversion.

The `makeCases()` function generates a tuple on the form `("Case",[])`.

EDIT: The code works fine locally but won't work in the hackerrank IDE

Comment: You're using `int(input())` in several places.  Obviously, `input()` is returning something other than a number string in one of those calls.  Find out what string you're passing to `int()` and fix it.  You could write your own `input_int` function that catches bad values and prints them out.  In any case, I don't think the problem has anything to do with concatenation.

Comment: Python3 or Python2?

Comment: You probably have an empty line, or the user just presses <RETURN>.  You should test the reply from `input()` before converting to an `int`, or use exception handling.

Comment: I was using python 3. The input strings are '3 ' for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

As Tom Karzes has said, `input()` is returning something other than a number. Looking at the error message that is produced by Python, I assume you are using Python 3 but I will cover Python 2 too.

## Python 2

`input()` checks if the given input from stdin is something it can `eval`uate to. It is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. ([Pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input))

```
>>> a = input()
123
>>> a
123
>>> abc = 3
>>> a = input()
abc
>>> a
3
```

It produces a different error when you `input()` something it cannot `eval`:

```
>>> a = input()
abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
```

Since it performs `eval` on the given input, it will assume that `abc` may be a variable name. It searches for it but throws an error because it couldn't find it.

## Python 3

`input()` is the new `raw_input()` in Python 2. `input()` returns a string even if the given input is a number. ([Pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input))

```
>>> a = input()
123
>>> a
'123'
```

This is the most likely reason you would convert it to an `int()` after you get an `input()`.

I can replicate your error message as so (in Python 3):

```
>>> a = int(input())
abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
>>> a = int(input())
123 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123 123'
```

In conclusion, the most likely reason why it is returning such an error is because you are giving it something it cannot convert to an `int`.